# How to about Gpars runForkJoin and forkOffChild methods

Tags: groovy, gpars

I'm trying to work with these methods with no success and i`ll be happy if someone can help me.
I'm using groovy and i have 2 maps of strings.
I want to match between the strings of the 2 maps with threads (using by gpars)
For example :
def firstMap = ["a":"A", "b":"B"]
def secondMap = ["c":"C", "a":A"]

The normal way to equale between the maps is to

```
fistMap.findAll().each { first ->
    secondMap.findAll.each { second ->
       if (first.key.equals(second.key) && (first.value.equlas(second.value))
         //saveItIntoArray
  }
}
```

I want to do it with gpars thread so i tried :

```
withPool(2) {
    runForkJoin(firstMap) { task ->
      task.each {
         secondMap.each {
            //equals
        }
        forChild(?)
     }
  }
}
```

I kind of new with this and i really don't know how to make it work.
I will appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Or.

Comment: A better way to do your first bit of code is `firstMap.findResult { fk, fv -> secondMap.findResult { sk, sv -> fk == sk && fv == sv ? [(fk):fv] : null } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd  suggest is using parallel collections:

```
def firstMap = ["a":"A", "b":"B"]
def secondMap = ["c":"C", "a":"A"].asImmutable()
withPool{
    println firstMap.findAllParallel { fk, fv -> secondMap.findResult { sk, sv -> fk == sk && fv == sv ? [(fk):fv] : null } }
}
```